# How to edit a xml attribute value using python script

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file where I have many project tags in which I want to edit revision attribute value using python script.

```
 <project remote="check" name="hardware/hwcomposer"
    path="hardware/check/hwcomposer"
    revision="14e7b7f9ba028b291c027812c95d64ec3a9da570"/>

 <project remote="check" name="hardware/weaver"
    path="hardware/check/weaver"
    revision="2c5c1719204699963e332cd92092665e99443220"/>
```

I am getting suggestions only for modifying the data in between the tag and not the attribute values of the tag and the xml file has many other tags too.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

tree = ET.parse('xml_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

print( root[7].attrib['path'])

if root[7].attrib['path'] == 'hardware/check/hwcomposer':
 root[7].attrib['revision'].text = 'changed_text_1'/* It is not working as root[7].attrib['revision'] returns a text and so not able to set the attribute value.
```

### Expected result:

```
.
.
 <project remote="check" name="hardware/hwcomposer" path="hardware/check/hwcomposer" revision="changed_text_1"/>

 <project remote="check" name="hardware/weaver" path="hardware/check/weaver" revision="changed_text_2"/>
.
.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Loop over the projects and change the revision attribute

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('in.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
projects = root.findall('.//project')
for idx, project in enumerate(projects):
    project.attrib['revision'] = 'changed_text_{}'.format(idx + 1)

tree.write(open('in.xml', 'wb'))
```

in.xml

```
<root>
    <project remote="check" name="hardware/hwcomposer"
             path="hardware/check/hwcomposer"
             revision="14e7b7f9ba028b291c027812c95d64ec3a9da570"/>

    <project remote="check" name="hardware/weaver"
             path="hardware/check/weaver"
             revision="2c5c1719204699963e332cd92092665e99443220"/>
</root>
```

Comment: It is printing the xml file with the changes but not editing in the xml file, I want these changes to be done in xml file

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You want the file  ('in.xml' in my example) to be changed?

Comment: Yes I wanted those to get updated, so when I open the xml file it should have the changes.

Comment: OK. Code was modified. See above.

Comment: Could you please explain me what is idx that you have used in the above script? Is it a mandatory one in this case?

Comment: Sure. We were looking for a running number: 1,2,3... in order to write the new revision. Each new revision needs its own number which is the previous number plus one. So I am using builtin enumerate in order to get this running number. See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate

Answer (score 0):

Reassign to `root[7].attrib['revision']`, not `root[7].attrib['revision'].text`, ie

```
root[7].attrib['revision'] = 'changed_text_1'
```

Comment: It did not work, do I need to open the xml file in the script? to modify the data, if so could you tell me as how to open and modify.

Comment: @venkatraman I don't understand your question. You already open the file in the code you provided.